# Loop for variables (Xcode 9 - swift 4)

Tags: swift, loops, variables

I have I think a stupid question for you, but I start Xcode just one week ago and I have a problem with a loop condition.

```
for index in 1...4 {
    AvatarPlayer1.layer.borderWidth = 4
    AvatarPlayer1.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    AvatarPlayer1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    AvatarPlayer1.layer.masksToBounds = false
    AvatarPlayer1.clipsToBounds = true //Mask for picture
}
```

How can I change the 1 value by for number in the loop.
I have try `+` , `+ \(index)`, `+ index`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change a variable name in code. Instead, start with an *array* of your four AvatarPlayer objects and cycle through the array:

```
let myArrayOfAvatarPlayers = [AvatarPlayer1, AvatarPlayer2, AvatarPlayer3, AvatarPlayer4]
for thisPlayer in myArrayOfAvatarPlayers {
    thisPlayer.layer.borderWidth = 4
    thisPlayer.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    thisPlayer.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    thisPlayer.layer.masksToBounds = false
    thisPlayer.clipsToBounds = true //Mask for picture
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In addition to matt's answer, you could move the setup up stuff to the object init or setup method.

After that, you could use `init(repeating:count:)` for the list's init. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641692-init